# How to pipe the content of a variable through two chained pipes in python?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I have successfully managed to pipe a variable to a command which is not piped further, in this way:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def exec_command(command, some_input):
    proc = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
    (stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate(input=some_input)
```

... but when trying to pipe it to a further piped command (for example piping to tar, and then further piping to split), it does not seem to work:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def exec_piped_command(command1, command2, some_input):
    proc1 = Popen(command1, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
    proc2 = Popen(command1, stdin=proc1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
    (stdout, stderr) = proc2.communicate(input=some_input)[0]
```

So, how is the correct way to do this second variant? It seems like the problem with the above code is that the input in the "proc2.communicate()" command does not reach the stdin pipe of proc1? (Not sure though ... unfortunatly I'm a bit confused about the subprocess syntax ...).

Comment: proc2.communicate is trying to feed some input into a PIPE, but the input PIPE for proc2 has been provided with the output PIPE from proc1 --- Unix pipes are not amenable to multiple writer/reader processes (they are NOT like Queue objects; nor like  sockets).  This probably is leading to a deadlock in your code.

Comment: Yeah, true, so my question is, how to I feed the variable to the input of proc1, and still execute the whole chained command? ... doing proc1.communicate(input=some_input) does not work either ...

Comment: Stylistic issue; `from x import *` is really bad and discouraged **all** of the time.

Comment: You could try proc1.stdin.write(...) ... however this might deadlock on a full buffer.  You might try fnctl operations to set the proc1.stdin into a non-blocking mode (and wrap the attempted write() calls in appropriate exception handling suites to handle the "EWOULDBLOCK" results).  If you do that then you probably one to do similar non-blocking manipulations on proc2's stdout and use read() calls on that rather than calling .communicate() at all.  As for the PIPE between proc1 and proc2 ... your Python process retains a copy of that which is useless to you and should be closed.

Comment: Note: you can't do anything useful about the blocking semantics between proc1 and proc2 ... but they shouldn't deadlock so long as you don't have a blocking and full buffer on either end of the pipeline.   If you needed more complex interactions among the processes (to make them into co-processes for example) then you'd have to interpose your own (Python) processes to actively relay data from one output pipe into another input pipe and so on --- or you'd have to have documented ways to limit these processes accommodate one another's buffering semantics.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jim for the explanations! I went for an easy solution for now, but it's much appreciated with these more detailed hints, since I'll probably run into a more demanding case sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to set up the entire command to be executed by a shell (`shell=True` to among the keyword args of your `Popen()` call ... and only `.communicate()` with the ends of the whole pipeline (your input going to command1's stdin, and your stdout/stderr coming from command2's stdout/stderr).

A more complicated, but fine grained, approach would be to use the `os.fork()` along with `os.pipe()` and `os.dup2()` and possibly some `os.fcntl()` calls to set up your own subprocesses, with your own custom plumping, and any of the desired blocking/non-blocking characteristics you need on your file descriptors and then, finally, using your own `os.exec*` functions in each of these.

This latter approach, obviously, would be duplicating quite a bit of the code that's already in the `subprocess` module.  However, it provides you the option of doing some of these steps differently in ways that are not exposed via the `subprocess.Popen` class.

The middle road would be to make a sub class that inherits from `subprocess.Popen`

Of course it may be preferable to perform some of the parts of this pipeline through Python code and modules (such as tar, gzip, and split operations).

Comment: Thanks, I went for the easy solution with shell=True. A bit less secure unfortunately, but I hope it will be OK when not adding any user-controllable strings to the command ...